# Can I use Blender 2.7 on my Macbook Pro 15" 2017?

Tags: osx

Can I use Blender 2.7 on my Macbook Pro 15" 2017? I have 3.1GHz Intel Core i7 processor, 16G memory, and my graphics card is Intel HD Graphics 630 1563 MB - I am anxious to start learning to use Blender, so I hope so, but I am a little confused by the details I see in the manual regarding requirements.  THANKS - Billy Beyond  - NYC

Comment: I learn Blender 2.79 with an older Macbook Pro than yours, so you won't have any problem. It's slower than a PC with Nvidia, but it's largely enough to learn. I'm not sure you'll be able to work with 2.8 though

Comment: Why don't you download and see if it runs? What happens when you try?